# hbase dns connection error or could be ipv6

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I have been trying to run MapReduce job that involves using Hbase as source and sink. However, when I try to use HBase client package 0.92.1, things seem to work. But when I use version 0.94.2 and above, it gave the following DNS related error. I want to use the newer HBase client package and hope someone can tell me what's wrong. Thanks

I have disabled IPv6 and not using it at all. I am not sure why it can't parse the string for the DNSclient.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:     "4f8:0:a102::add:9999"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:458)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.<init>(DnsClient.java:103)
at com.sun.jndi.dns.Resolver.<init>(Resolver.java:44)
at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContext.getResolver(DnsContext.java:553)
at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContext.c_getAttributes(DnsContext.java:413)
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_getAttributes(ComponentDirContext.java:213)
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:121)
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLDirContext.getAttributes(GenericURLDirContext.java:85)
at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.getAttributes(InitialDirContext.java:123)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.reverseDns(DNS.java:85)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.reverseDNS(TableInputFormatBase.java:219)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.getSplits(TableInputFormatBase.java:184)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:1064)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:1081)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$600(JobClient.java:174)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:993)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:946)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:946)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:566)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:596)
at hbase_mapred1.FreqCounter1.main(FreqCounter1.java:86)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a known problem in Java. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6991580, I am sure that there is an Oracle bug as well, but couldn't find it.

Comment: Hi, actually I was able to solve this problem last time already. It was because of the incompatibility of Hadoop version with HBase as pointed out by Ignacio Sales below. I can confirmed that HBase 0.94.2 is working with some versions of Hadoop but not all.

Answer (score 0):

In general you should be very careful when mixing HBase and Hadoop versions, as they often do not play well with each other. Something which really helps there is using something like Cloudera's distribution, which bundles compatible versions of HBase / Hadoop / Hive / Pig, etc...

Is there any specific reason why you want to use the 0.94.2 version of HBase?

Comment: Thanks for your ans. Actually, Im using cloudera distribution shipped with HBase 0.94.2 but the issue is, using the HBase java client 0.94.2 causes the above error while using HBase java client 0.92.1 seems to work just fine. I was just curious whether other people are facing the same issues or maybe it's just me.